# Is there a way to use Big5 Encoding in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, unicode, cjk

I know that WP7 does not have Big5 encoding, but I want to encode a web page in Big5. How do I encode a string from Unicode to Big5 in WP7?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Joey Right. Not that the OP is paying attention... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get you started is to get a conversion table setup. I put up [such a table](http://pastebin.com/ZBZ9mdNz) on pastebin. It's `;` separated, and the first codepoint is Unicode, whereas the second one is Big5.

Of course if it's for a web page, I think the whole exercise is futile and pointless, since you could just declare the charset as utf-8 and be done with it...